# Going randomly from state s1 to state s2 given probability

Tags: c#, random, state

Ok, suppose I have a class `foo` with a "state" propriety.  I need a function which chooses randomly a new state with these restrictions: Some transitions are not allowed and every transition has a different probability to happen.

```
enum PossibleStates { A, B, C, D }
PossibleStates currentState;

float[,] probabilities;
```

`probabilities[s1, s2]` tells the probability of going from state s1 to state s2. It can also be 0.0f meaning that s1->s2 isn't possible and `probabilities[s1, s2]` can be different from `probabilities[s2, s1]`. I need this method to be as general as possible, so that there can be three as well as three-hundred possible states.
This isn't homework, I just need a good starting point because I don't know where to begin from :)

Cheers

Comment: How important is performance?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: not much, as long it is less than O(n^18) ;)

Comment: You can get rid of `allowedTransitions` by setting the appropriate probabilities to `0`.

Comment: Do you need allowedTransitions, could you not just have a probablility of 0 for non allowed transitions.

Comment: @vlad, damn you beat me to it ;-)

Comment: @Ben: well, only by 15 seconds :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fully functional example following. F5 this then tap ENTER to change state.
in the `States` class you can define your probabilities and states.

in my code i assume routes are mutually exclusive(their combined probability never goes above 1). i've marked the piece of code to change if that's not true.

```
namespace RandomStatesProgram
{
    class State
    {
        public string Name;

        private bool current;
        public bool Current
        {
            get { return current; }
            set
            {
                if (current)
                {
                    if (value) StayingHere();
                    else LeavingState();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (value) EnteringState();
                }

                current = value;
            }
        }

        public void StayingHere() { Console.WriteLine("Staying in state " + this.Name); }
        public void EnteringState() { Console.WriteLine("Entering state " + this.Name); }
        public void LeavingState() { Console.WriteLine("Leaving state " + this.Name); }

        public State()
        {
            this.Name = "New";
            this.Current = false;
        }

        public State(string name)
            : this()
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }

    class TransitionCourse
    {
        public State From { get; set; }
        public State To { get; set; }
        public float Probability { get; set; }

        public TransitionCourse(Dictionary<int, State> allStates, int fromState, int toState, float probability)
        {
            if (probability < 0 || probability > 1)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid probability");

            if (!allStates.Keys.Any(K => K == fromState || K == toState))
                throw new ArgumentException("State not found");

            this.From = allStates[fromState];
            this.To = allStates[toState];
            this.Probability = probability;
        }
    }

    static class States
    {
        private static Dictionary<int, State> PossibleStates;
        public static State Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (PossibleStates.Where(S => S.Value.Current).Count() == 1)
                    return PossibleStates.Single(S => S.Value.Current).Value;
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }

        public static List<TransitionCourse> Transitions;

        static States()
        {
            PossibleStates = new Dictionary<int, State>()
            {
                {1, new State("One")}, 
                {2, new State("Two")}, 
                {3, new State("Three")},
                {4, new State("Four")} 
            };

            // example: 50% chance of switching to either state from every one of the three
            // note: it must be  0 <= 3rd param <= 1 of course (it's a probability)
            Transitions = new List<TransitionCourse>()
            {
                new TransitionCourse(PossibleStates,1,2,1f/3f),
                new TransitionCourse(PossibleStates,1,3,1f/3f),
                new TransitionCourse(PossibleStates,1,4,1f/3f),
                new TransitionCourse(PossibleStates,2,1,1f),            
                new TransitionCourse(PossibleStates,3,1,1f),
                new TransitionCourse(PossibleStates,4,1,1f)               
            };
        }

        public static void GoTo(int targetState)
        {
            if (!PossibleStates.Keys.Contains(targetState))
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid state");

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, State> state in PossibleStates.OrderByDescending(S=>S.Value.Current))
            {
                //first is the "true" state (the current one) then the others.
                //this way we go OUT from a state before going IN another one.
                state.Value.Current = state.Key.Equals(targetState);
            }
        }

        public static void Travel()
        {
            if (Current == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Current state not set");

            TransitionCourse[] exits = Transitions.Where(T => T.From.Equals(Current)).OrderBy(T=>T.Probability).ToArray();
            if (exits.Length == 0) //nowhere to go from here
                return;
            else
                if (exits.Length == 1) //not much to choose here
                {
                    GoTo(PossibleStates.Single(S => S.Value.Equals(exits.First().To)).Key);
                }
                else //ok now we have a choice
                {
                    //we need a "random" number
                    double p = new Random().NextDouble();

                    // remapping probabilities so we can choose "randomly"
                    // this works IF the sum of all transitions probability does not exceed 1.
                    // if it does, at best this'll act weird
                    for (int i = 1; i < exits.Length; i++)
                    {
                        exits[i].Probability += exits[i - 1].Probability;
                        if (exits[i].Probability > p)
                        {
                            GoTo(PossibleStates.Single(S => S.Value.Equals(exits[i].To)).Key);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            States.GoTo(1);
            while (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() != "Q")
            {
                States.Travel();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a beginner in C# so I'll need some time to understand it though ;)

Answer (score 2):

For a transition from the state A, you calculate a (uniformly distributed) random number `r` between 0 and 1. you have the probabilities of transition: `p1`, `p2`, ..., `pn`, their sum obviously must be 1. Now, if `r < p1`, you follow the first transition; otherwise, if `r < p1 + p2`, you follow the second transition, and so on.

P.S.: in order to produce the needed random number, you get a (single) `Random` object, and call [`NextDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx) method:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
...
double r = rnd.NextDouble();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's say that we have a function that produce a random value between 1 and 100.

Let's call this function

```
 float GetRandomNumber()
 {    
     ....
 }
```

Now let's assume we want to generate three numbers that have probabilities to happen following two cases:

case 1)

probabilities are mutually exclusive, i.e. if one happens, the others cannot happen

case 2)

probabilities are independent, so they happen with their own probability

let's see what happend for 1:

```
  var mutuallyExclusiveProbs = new List<float>({30,50,20});
  var number = GetRandomNumber();
  var cumulativeValue =0;
  //
  for (int i=0; i++; i<mutuallyExclusiveProbs.Count())
  {
    cumulativeValue += mutuallyExclusiveProbs(i)
    if (number <=cumulativeValue)
    {
       //case found 
       return i;
    }
  }
```

while for 2 it is easier

```
  var mutuallyExclusiveProbs = new List<float>({30,50,20});
  var number = GetRandomNumber();
  return mutuallyExclusiveProbs.Where(x=>x<=number );
```

I have written the code directly, it may not compile but, I think the point of what i am doing is shown.

Hope it helps.